# Historical sql Table With Bits Of User Information - Make New Table With 1 Entry & All Information

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table (customers) that has 43 columns of user information (first name, last name, address, city, state, zip, phone, email, visitDate, lastActive, etc...)

Every night, I'm getting a feed from our clients with the customers that visited them that day.  These visits are stored into the customers table without removing the old record.  The old record is marked lastActive = 0 and the new one is marked lastActive = 1. Any null fields are stored as "Unknown".

Obviously this results in a very large table that takes a while to query.  So, I plan on making a new table that is only the distinct users and their most complete information.

For example: If Bob Smith was imported on January 1st with no phone or email, and then he was imported again on August 1st with a phone, but no email, and then imported again on September 1st with no phone, but an email, my customers table would look something like this:

```
CustImportID  CustomerKey  FirstName  LastName  Phone      Email   visitDate   lastActive
1             1            Bob        Smith     Unknown    Unknown 2016-01-01  0
2             1            Bob        Smith     5551231234 Unknown 2016-08-01  0
3             1            Bob        Smith     Unknown    1@2.io  2016-09-01  1
```

So my question is this, what's the best way to get the distinct people from the customers table, and insert them into the new table where Bob would only be one entry, but I would have values for every field (if every entry has phone, for example, we would pull the phone from the most recent entry), resulting is something like this:

```
CustomerKey  FirstName  LastName  Phone      Email  visitDate   
1            Bob        Smith     5551231234 1@2.io 2016-09-01
```

Comment: The only way I could even think of doing it would be to have a query that contains 43 sub-queries - which clearly isn't the best way to do it.  I know there's got to be a better way, but I can't can't think of one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`FIRST_VALUE`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx) with a trick to ignore `'Uknown'` values:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName,
       FIRST_VALUE(Phone) OVER (ORDER BY CASE 
                                            WHEN Phone='Unknown' THEN 1 
                                            ELSE 0
                                         END,
                                         visitDate DESC) AS Phone,
       FIRST_VALUE(Email) OVER (ORDER BY CASE 
                                            WHEN Email='Unknown' THEN 1 
                                            ELSE 0
                                         END,
                                         visitDate DESC) AS Email
FROM mytable
```

`FIRST_VALUE` is available from SQL Server 2012. It picks the latest field value as specified by the `ORDER BY` of the `OVER` clause. Due the `CASE` in the `ORDER BY` clause, `'Unknown'` values will have to lowest priority.

Answer (score 0):

you can use max of values from all records which will result this:

```
select customerkey, max(firstname), max(lastname), max(phone), max(email), max(visitdate) from yourtablename
```

If you have two are more valid entries then use row_number and select max of that based on recent values

Comment: I had thought about the row number, but then I'd have to do a row number over every field.